# TypeError when drawing circle in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-physics

I am trying to draw all bodies in a pybox2d world with pygame, and I receive this error message when running the code:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), position, radius)

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

It seems that pygame is expecting integers in position, and that is what the error is for. However, I am converting the position into integers explicitly, so this shouldn't be a problem.
The code for this project is the following:
main.py

```
import pygame
from circle import Circle
from draw import Draw
from Box2D import b2World

PPM = 20
TARGET_FPS = 60
TIME_STEP = 1.0 / TARGET_FPS

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# A list for all of our rectangles
world = b2World(gravity=(0, 30), doSleep=True)


close = False

while not close:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            close = True
    
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    
    circle = Circle(world,300,300,PPM)
    
    Draw(screen,world.bodies,PPM)
    
    world.Step(TIME_STEP, 10, 10)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(TARGET_FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

circle.py

```
from Box2D import (b2FixtureDef, b2CircleShape)

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, world, x, y, PPM):
        self.x = x / PPM
        self.y = y / PPM
        self.r = 1

        self.world = world
        self.body = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(
            position=(self.x, self.y),
            fixtures=b2FixtureDef(
                shape=b2CircleShape(radius = self.r), density=2.0, friction = 0.5))
```

draw.py

```
import pygame

def Circle(screen,body,fixture,PPM):
    shape = fixture.shape
    radius = shape.radius
    position = (int(body.position.x * PPM),int(body.position.y * PPM))
    
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), position, radius)


def Draw(screen,PPM,bodies):
    for body in bodies:
        for fixture in body.fixtures:
            try:
                Circle(screen,body,fixture,PPM)
            except: pass
            Circle(screen,body,fixture)
```

I feel this is very simple but I do not understand what the problem in this code is.

Comment: Is this the only call of `pygame.draw.circle`?  Are you sure the components of the _center_ argument are always integers?

Comment: You can use [integer division](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) `//` to ensure your integers aren't changed to floating-point numbers by division. E.g.: `self.x = x // PPM`

Comment: Check to see if your integers are not floating-point numbers by using `print()`

Answer (score 0):

The components of the *center* argument of [`pygame.draw.circle`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) must be integral. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates:

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), position, radius)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (round(position[0]), round(position[1])), radius)
```